# из hex перевести в текст

Tags: java, android, unicode, hex

Код, который выполняется на сервере (*c#*)

```
public static string ToHexString(string str) 
{ 
    var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str); 
    foreach (var t in bytes) 
    { 
        sb.Append(t.ToString("X2")); 
    } 

    return sb.ToString();
}

public static string FromHexString(string hexString) 
{ 
    var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) 
    { 
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16); 
    } 

    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes); // returns: "Hello world" for "48656C6C6F20776F726C64"

}
```

**Проблема**: если перевести русские слова в hex, то в java я не могу обратно перевести в нормальный текст. А с английскими словами все нормально.

На сервере получается вот такая строка hex

3400370020003D043504340435043B044F04200033043E043404300420002D00200041043E043704340430043B0420003D043E0432044B0439042000 30043A0442043804320420003D04300420004D044204430420003D043504340435043B044E04

из текста "47 неделя ...."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ваша задача решается достаточно просто с помощью Apache Commons Codec:

```
String result = new String(Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray()), CharEncoding.UTF_16LE);
```

Ссылка на MavenRepo: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11

Comment: Спасибо! метод работает!

Comment: Не за что, пользуйтесь